# Need help adding Django model object via form

Tags: django, django-views

In my django based project, I have a 'Field' model that the user can add via a form.

The view that gets called upon loading the page is this.

```
@login_requred
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # do 'Field' saving stuff
        HttpResponseRedirect('/index/')
    else:
        # some code ...
        return render(request, 'precisionagweb/index.html', {# stuff to render})
```

And the form in index.html is

```
<form id="addFieldForm" class="ui form" method="post">
    form stuff
</form>
```

This approach works fine, but I want to change the structure by creating a view that is specifically for adding a 'Field', so I can avoid an overly complex function definition for index when I add in modification and delete features.

My approach was to create a view like this:

```
@login_required
def user_addField(request):
    print 'made it here'
    addField_form = addField(data=request.POST)
    if addField_form.is_valid():
        field = addField_form.save(commit=False)
        field.user = request.user
        field.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/index/')
```

remove the POST stuff from the index definition like this:

```
@login_requred
def index(request):
    # some code
    return render(request, 'precisionagweb/index.html', {# stuff to render})
```

and change the "action" in the form like this:

```
<form id="addFieldForm" class="ui form" method="post" action="addField/">
    form stuff
</form>
```

My urls are configured like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^signup/', views.signup),
    url(r'^index/', views.index),
    url(r'^addField/', views.user_addField),
    url(r'^login/', views.user_login),
    url(r'^logout/', views.user_logout),
]
```

This does not work because the print statement in my new view definition never prints to the terminal, and thus the view never gets called. I do not know what to do at this point, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Usually a view like this would look like this:

```
def add_field(request):
    form = AddFieldForm(data=request.POST or None)

    if form.is_valid():
        field = form.save(commit=False)
        field.user = request.user
        field.save()

        return redirect('named_url')

    return render(request, 'template.html', { 'form': form })
```

The concept behind this is easy: This view is responsible for showing the actual form to the user aswell as actually storing your new object.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Correct me if I'm wrong, but are you suggesting that I should stick with just one view for everything? The view that you wrote looks similar to my original index definition.

Comment: No, I would not recommend this! But I would use one specific view for one task within your app: adding fields. Without knowing your application, I can not say, which other views you may need...

Comment: Thanks again for your help! I figured out the problem, it seems that I needed to add a slash in the action parameter: "/addField/".